# Compare two folders and copy missing files to new folder based on sequence numbers using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have two folders with sequentially numbered files. Folder "Originals" contains all the files, but some are missing in folder "Modified". Is there a way to copy those that are missing in folder "Modified" from folder "Originals" to a new folder using bash?
The files are different in content and filename, but are related in their filename's ending numbering.

The files are still images - .png - from a video that have been modified using Imagemagick. Ten folders each contain 15000 images, with about 100 missing irregularly from each "Modified" folder due to errors while processing with Imagemagick.

```
Originals:
xy_abc_00000.png
xy_abc_00001.png
xy_abc_00002.png
.
.
xy_abc_15000.png


Modified:
zz_def_00000.png
zz_def_00002.png
.
.
zz_def_14999.png
```

Comment: Have you already tried something on your own?

Comment: I managed to print a list of the missing files and worked on an apple script but didn‘ t manage the whole process yet. I m not very experienced with shell scripts yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list="$(diff <(ls -X Originals | sed "s:^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*.png\)$:\1:") \
             <(ls -X Modified  | sed "s:^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*.png\)$:\1:"))"
for file in $(grep "^<" <<<"$list" | cut -d" " -f2); do
    cp Originals/xy_abc_$file Modified/zz_def_$file
done
```

Not overly elegant, would break on names with spaces, but still suitable for the task described in the OP post.

Comment: Thanks for your help @hidefromkgb ! I should have mentioned i'm using Terminal on Mac OS X. Works perfectly when leaving the -X option out from ls. (can't upvote yet, but thanks)